# Override Extension Helper

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, helper, magento-1.9.3.3

I'm trying to override a part of an helper of Help Desk MX extension.
So I created a module with the following file:
`app/etc/modules/company.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <Company_Helpdesk>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_Helpdesk>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Company/Helpdesk/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Helpdesk>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_Helpdesk>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mirasvit_helpdesk>
                <rewrite>
                    <email>Company_Helpdesk_Helper_Email</data>
                </rewrite>
            </mirasvit_helpdesk>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Company/Helpdesk/Helper/Email.php`

```
<?php
class Company_Helpdesk_Helper_Email extends Mirasvit_Helpdesk_Helper_Email
{
    public function getHiddenSeparator()
    {
        return "<span style='color:transparent;font-size:0;margin:0px;padding:0px;'>".$this->getSeparator().'</span>';
    }   
}
```

Following this guide: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

But it doesn't work.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: In the original module that you are overwriting, how does the `<helpers>` tag look like?

Comment: `        <helpers>
            <helpdesk>
                <class>Mirasvit_Helpdesk_Helper</class>
            </helpdesk>
        </helpers>
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this  in your `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <mirasvit_helpdesk>
            <rewrite>
                <email>Company_Helpdesk_Helper_Email</email>
            </rewrite>
        </mirasvit_helpdesk>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

to this

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <helpdesk><!-- this needs to match the tag in the original module -->
            <rewrite>
                <email>Company_Helpdesk_Helper_Email</email>
            </rewrite>
        </helpdesk>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

also, in your `app/etc/modules/company.xml` add this inside the `Company_Helpdesk` tag

```
<depends>
     <Mirasvit_Helpdesk />
</depends>
```

Comment: in `<rewrite>` tag Helper class has different closing tag

Answer (score 0):

Here i am show you how to Extend community Or third party module helper class in your own modules.
Now here i am extend asmaty extension helper.

1. create your module register xml  `app/etc/modules/Myextend_Shopbyextend.xml`

   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Myextend_Shopbyextend>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
               <depends>
                   <Amasty_Shopby />
               </depends>
           </Myextend_Shopbyextend>
       </modules>
   </config>`
2. create module `config.xml` file `app/code/local/Myextend/Shopbyextend/etc/`

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
       <Myextend_Shopbyextend> 
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Myextend_Shopbyextend>
   </modules>
   <global>
        <helpers>
           <shopbyextend>
               <class>Myextend_Shopbyextend_Helper</class>
           </shopbyextend>
           <amshopby>
               <rewrite>
                   <data>Myextend_Shopbyextend_Helper_Data</data> 
               </rewrite>
           </amshopby>
        </helpers>

   </global>
</config>`

3. Last create your help file `app/code/local/Plumtree/Shopbyextend/Helper/Data.php` and extends Amasty_Shopby_Helper_Data class

`class Myextend_Shopbyextend_Helper_Data extends Amasty_Shopby_Helper_Data
{
  public function getCurrentCategory()
    { 
          \\ Write your code here 
    }
}`

I hope this will help you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/124020)

Comment: Ok. thank you for your suggestion @Piyush