# How to display regions list sorted by region_id

Tags: magento-1.9, regions

Thank you for making your attention to my question.

I'd like to show Region List ordered by region_id on the DB with RegionUpdater.
Currently its ordered by Region's name alphabet.
I tried to modified the following files but haven't succeed to change it.

Modified file: "./app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php"
tried to add "->setOrder('region_id', 'ASC')"

Our environment is Magento 1.9.3.1.

If you have any idea to solve this, let me have your help.[image]

Regards,
7steps

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the _Config_ cache?

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure to never modify core files. Always try to overwrite the classes in your own module. Click [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181545/override-extension-helper)  for help overwriting a helper.

In your overwritten class you should override this method with the following code:

```
public function getRegionCollection()
{
    if (!$this->_regionCollection) {
        $this->_regionCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()
            ->addCountryFilter($this->getAddress()->getCountryId())
            ->setOrder('region_id', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
            ->load();
    }
    return $this->_regionCollection;
}
```

Regions in the table `directory_country_region` are by default sorted by alphabetically, so doing this would make no effect unless you changed the region ids yourself. Which I not recommend you do.